# In file './docker-compose.yml', service 'proxy-nginx' must be a mapping not a string?

Tags: docker, nginx, docker-compose

I have the following `docker-compose.yml` file:

```
    version: '3'

    services:
      proxy-nginx:
        build:./nginx
      ports:
        - 80:80
```

When I run `docker-compose up the console logs:

```
In file './docker-compose.yml', service 'proxy-nginx' must be a mapping not a string.
```

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37632244/docker-compose-error-in-file-docker-compose-yml-service-punjab-must-be-a) suggests using quotes around the ports:

```
    version: '3'

    services:
      proxy-nginx:
        build:./nginx
      ports:
        - "80:80"
```

Also tried indenting ports more:

```
    version: '3'
    services:
      proxy-nginx:
        build:./nginx
        ports:
          - 80:80
```

But the result is still the same.  Any ideas?

Comment: `build: ./nginx` instead of `build:./nginx`? Missing space?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Docker compose error "In file './docker-compose.yml', service 'punjab' must be a mapping not a string."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37632244/docker-compose-error-in-file-docker-compose-yml-service-punjab-must-be-a)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try indenting *ports* properly:

```
    version: '3'
    services:
      gogs-nginx:
        build: ./nginx
        ports:
        - "80:80"
```

I think the problem is that the parser thinks *ports* is another service because of the misleading indentation. I can't blame it for that though.

Comment: Tried it and added it to the question.  Any other ideas?

Comment: I updated the answer with quotes around the port values.  I tried doing that earlier as well, but it was still not working for some reason.  So I copied a snippet from the docker site (https://docs.docker.com/compose/gettingstarted/#step-3-define-services-in-a-compose-file) and changed it and now it works...